# Axios and Blade in Laravel, how ? For Async request category filter

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, axios

I need to make a category filter for my blog posts. I was toying around with Vue a bit. But since I have not learned Vue, I was recommended to just use Axios. I am completely lost. How does it work? I cannot even log a result from here? I did get it to work with an example in the App.JS from a SO question, trying to find that again.  But thats Vue? I am not sure what to do anymore ?  This is my example the /axios refers to a controller I show the controller first then the blade :

```
    class AxiosController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    $articles = Article::all();
    //$categories = Category::all();
    return response()->json($articles); 
    }
}
```

The blade ( I had it without the axios.create and all kinds of try outs I did) I also did it without the @once and the @push I just read this in the Laravel documentation.

```
  @once
     @push('scripts')
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js">
    
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/axios',
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
    });
    
    const axios = require('axios');
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/axios')
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
    </script>
    @endpush
    @endonce
```

Comment: It would be well worth learning Laravel Mix and Webpack and how to properly compile javascript and sass assets with Babel

Comment: Babel ? So if I have to learn Vue in the future anyway, I better just learn Vue and Axios and then compiling using Babel ?

Comment: I have Axios installed, I understand the webpackage slightly and now the same get requests works. So the code is correct but to use it with Laravel is different. Now to see how to filter things.